# Changing the value of Chrome sync does not work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The value was changed to **"pass"** from the original value **"update"** but was not reflected in sync.

```
function setSyncListData(){
   chrome.storage.sync.set({"data":data.reverse()},function(){
      console.log("saved");
      console.log(data);
      chrome.storage.sync.get("data",function(load){
         console.log("load");
         console.log(load.data);
      });
   });
}
```

[image: Chrome Console log]

Can I tell you why I didn't do anything wrong or why?

Comment: If you want to see the real value at the time the code runs use console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) otherwise the object will be expanded using its value at the time you expand it in the console, not when the code runs.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].